# Modifying properties in a C# list of objects in parallel

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

I have a list containing objects and I wish to run operations against each list item in parallel. One of those operations involves modifying a property of the object. I thought that shouldn't cause an issue thread-safety wise, but my unit test is failing randomly, so I'm worried there is a race condition.

The exact failure case is that the test will fail saying that the list is empty, but only if I run my my test regularly, if I run in debug mode the problem disappears. None of my code should be removing/adding elements, the list is generated at the start and then never directly modified, only the elements themselves are modified.

Is modifying properties on classes in a C# list threadsafe?

Here is the code in question:

```
List<ExampleObject> localApplications = MethodThatProducesTheList();

Parallel.ForEach(localApplications, localitem =>
{
    if (localitem.BuildLabel.Contains("_Release_"))
    {
        // Delete applications from the old system
        var appToDelete = Path.Combine(AppRootPath, localitem.Name, localitem.BuildLabel);
        DeleteDirectory(appToDelete);
    }
    else
    {
        var st = MethodThatGetsTheState(localitem.BuildLabel);

        localitem.State.Add(st);
    }
});
```

Here is a more minimal example:

```
var object = new { 
    prop = "foo"
};
var list = new[] { object }.ToList();

Parallel.ForEach(list, listItem =>
{
    listItem.prop = "bar";
});

if (list[0].prop != "bar") {
    Assert.Fail()
}
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve].

Comment: Multiple *Threads* that access the one *resource* should always *ring alarm-bells* that its not *thread safe*, unless you can live with and understand whats going on and the consequences

Comment: How is it failing, I don't see any asserts so is it throwing an exception?

Comment: Let me throw together a runnable example. The asserts are in the test code and the result I'm getting is the list being empty when I expect it to have 1 element.

Comment: I don't see a shared resource here you are modifying object, which is assigned to a specific thread, this shall work, issue is only when there's a shared resource

Comment: Your updated example wouldn't have a problem as the properties will never interact, and also should pass your test

Comment: Thread safety comes into play when multiple threads try to modify the same resource. In your case, you're iterating through the list and giving each thread its very own object to play with, and you're not modifying the list itself. All is good.

Comment: Okay. I'll have to assume the problem with the list becoming empty is occurring elsewhere in the code. I wasn't sure about the internals of the C# list construct so I thought it might be doing something I wasn't aware of. Someone can post a response containing this and I'll mark solved.

Comment: Oh... if you **adding** and **removing** items from a List in different *threads*, your are going to make a perfect example of an `Exception` throwing application. *Lists* are based on *arrays*, *arrays* are chunks of *memory*, and that *memory* may *move* when the *array* is expanded.

Comment: Your question says nothing about an error due to a list becoming empty. That seems like it could be relevant information to include.

Comment: The code doesn't add or remove items from the list. I've also added more information about the exact error case.

Comment: There's no reason to add any kind of locking mechanism if you are granting each thread/task an element of the list. You are not adding/deleting elements,nor are you reading elements that are changed by other threads.One other method you could try besides `Parallel.Foreach` is using `Task<something> [] tasks` and run each list element on a `Task`.

Comment: Is it possible your list is being shared between tests? If `MethodThatProducesTheList()` returns a static list variable it could be a case where other tests are modifying the list reference. I haven't seen anything yet that looks responsible for the behavior you are experiencing.

Comment: I'm thinking this is related to the test runner. Can you share a smaller reproducable example? What testing framework are you using and what runner? NUnit, XUnit?

Comment: `Here is a more minimal example:` So, just to be clear - that **exact** minimal example test fails when you run it?

Comment: You are running different code in **Debug** and **Release** mode. This is alarming. Also the check of the build mode is performed inside the parallel loop by different threads, instead of using a clean [preprosessor directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/) `#if DEBUG`. What does `DeleteDirectory` do?

Comment: Different code is *not* running in Debug and Release mode.
I figured out the issue was a timing problem elsewhere in the code (one of the calls was interacting with a singleton and producing bad behavior).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, so the issue causing my problem wasn't a race case in the ForEach, but instead the combination of a timing issue and a singleton being shared in the test environment.

However, my original question was simply whether it was safe to use a C# list across threads assuming that the operations carried out with each list element were themselves threadsafe. In other words, is using Parallel.ForEach on a List just as thread safe/unsafe as doing a similar operation on an array. From the comments of users here, it appears the answer is **yes**.

Namely, that so far as thread safety goes a List can be considered equivalent to an array assuming the user isn't adding or removing elements from the list, sorting the list, etc.

Comment: This is why it is **critical** the next time something like this happens that you provide a [mcve]. The tendency of most programmers when they encounter an issue is to rush into blinkered mode - assuming they understand where the issue is. A [mcve] forces you to spend the time to narrow down the cause, rather than make assumptions too soon.

Comment: Yeah, I think I was unclear. I tried to be clear that my concern was just whether it was in general thread safe to mutate the items in a List. I was fine figuring out any other issues on my own. I wasn't able to find a clear answer to the thread safety question specifically elsewhere.

Comment: The docs are generally very clear on thread safety - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.8#thread-safety .